# How to hide parent folder in netrw of vim

Tags: vim, netrw

While working with file1.c, I've entered netrw, typing `:edit .` In the netrw window, the example directory list are shown like this.

```
folder2/
| folderAA/
| | file1.c
| | file2.c
```

In that, I typed `-` to view parent window, and the directory view are changed like this.

```
folderA/
| folder1/
| folder2/
| | folderAA/
| | | file1.c
| | | file2.c
```

Now I have no need to see folderA. But how can I hide that folderA? I can't find command. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

- Put cursor on folderA
- Press `<Enter>`

This operation will open the folder (if closed) *and* close the folder (if open).

Comment: That second step should be:  Press [return].

Comment: If you meant that you'd like to change the top-of-the-tree, see  :help :Ntree.  If your version of netrw doesn't support :Ntree, upgrade to the most recent: http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW .